# Unable to access httpd on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Hi I setup an ec2 instance and I am able to ping the instance but unable to access it via the browser.

httpd is running and my ports are configured as below.

```
ICMP
Port (Service)  Source  Action
ALL 0.0.0.0/0   Delete
TCP
Port (Service)  Source  Action
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0   Delete
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   Delete
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0   Delete
8080 (HTTP*)    0.0.0.0/0   Delete
UDP
Port (Service)  Source  Action
53 (DNS)    0.0.0.0/0   Delete
```

Can you help me with what I am missing here.. seems very odd, since I have my other instance setup the same way and works like a charm

Comment: Please check your security-group to see if the port HTTPD running on, is open.

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to [EC2 Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home)
2. Go to Security Groups in left menu (under NETWORK & SECURITY)
3. Select used Security Group
4. Go to "Inbound" tab
5. Create new rule: HTTP, 0.0.0.0/0
6. Click 'Add Rule'
7. Click 'Apply Rule Changes'

Answer (score 2):

I figured out.. It was iptables.

```
service iptables stop
```

and now it works. 
Again, I don't care about what iptables should allow/deny. If you do, please configure it accordingly

Comment: `iptables` doesn't typically come configured on your instance; how could that even be the issue? :)

Comment: This helped me. I was literally pulling my hair to figure out why I cannot access my instance from the browser. I did exactly what you suggested and it works. I don't care about iptables on my EC2 host as Amazon manages security via security groups which is essentially a "firewall" of sorts.